# multiply a list by list of lists - prolog

Tags: list, prolog, multiplication, calculation

How to multiply a list by list of lists?

- **Example:**
- [[1,2],[3,5]],[5,0]] * [2]
- result = [[2,4],[6,10],[10,0]]

Comment: Can use e.g. `[X] = Lst` to easily extract the single element.

Answer (score 1):

Is seems a bit odd to receive one of the operands of the multiplication as the single item of a list.

You may use `maplist` twice from library [`apply`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply) to apply an operation over every item of your input and build back a new list with the multiplication applied:

```
multiply_l(L, [M], R):-
  maplist(maplist(multiply(M)), L, R).
  
multiply(A, B, C):- C is A*B.
```

Sample run:

```
?- multiply_l([[1,2],[3,5],[5,0]], [2], R).
R = [[2, 4], [6, 10], [10, 0]].
```

Comment: Then you would probably want to split the computation. Something like `multiply_l(L, LM, R):-  maplist(multiply1, L, LM, R).` which would use helper procedure `multiply1(L, M, R):- maplist(multiply(M), L, R).`. I guess maplist is not flexible enough to write it as a one-liner unless you use lambda expressions.